# What is the appropriate recourse for trolls?

Tags: discussion, site-policies

A user has taken to commenting on many of my posts, calling me out for having a lack of understanding and providing misinformation.  Correcting misinformation is a great idea and encouraged, and I accept that I am not infallible and am likely to make mistakes.

However, the way he is going about doing it is borderline harassment, and I'm not sure how to react. What recourse does this site have for such posts?

To make it clear, this question is more focused on how he goes about making his points than the points themselves.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The appropriate response would be to flag the posts in question and ignore them. Never attack them directly, there's no use and it just results in a flame war. If you simply flag the moderators will be able to deal with it without stirring up conflict.

Comment: This pretty much sums it up. If someone is being openly confrontational, **flag it for moderator attention**. Don't do petty things like downvote or flag as spam if it doesn't otherwise imply. And do not engage either. Neither the user in question, nor Lu Bu.

Comment: @Grace I'll have you know I've kicked Lu Bu's ass in every Dynasty Warriors game from 2-6.  Lu Bu maybe scary, but ultimately he'll separate himself from his allies and leave himself vulnerable.

Comment: I just play as Lu Bu because I suck at Dynasty Warriors.

Comment: @tzenes If you think about it, Lu Bu kinda was the troll of the Three Kingdoms era.

Comment: @Grace he was definitely a troll