# How can I report users?

Tags: support, editing, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the appropriate recourse for trolls?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/874/what-is-the-appropriate-recourse-for-trolls)

Fr example, when someone is being rude in comments, personally attacking, and instead of being on-topic proceeds instead to attack the OP when they didn't even have anything useful to post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For isolated instances, flagging their messages with an appropriate reason is enough (such as "rude/offensive". If it's a repeated pattern of abuse, flagging one such message with a custom reason explaining the situation is your best way to report such behavior. Ideally you should include links to examples of said abuse, to further support your case. In both cases a mod will take the time to review your flag, and decide if any action is warranted.